# Get same alignement of posted datas with http_build_query

Tags: php

I have this php code:

```
function submit_query(array $req = array()) {
  $post_data = http_build_query($req, '', '&');
  curl_submit($post_data, $my_url);
}
```

I submit data via `post` like this (each time i use random alignement):

```
submit_query(array('code1' => "code1", 'code2' => "code2"));
```

I want to get same alignement of submited datas `$post_data = http_build_query($req, '', '&');` in the target file `$my_url`.

Any advice ? Thank's.

Comment: What do you mean by alignment? The order of the options in the query? You can always sort by keys in both `submit_query` and the target file to get the same order ...

Comment: yes the order of the options. I can't because the arguments will be entered by other users ... and users have their own order.

Comment: Who do you refer to by "user"? The user of your submit_query? Or a user of the page wo submits a form?

Comment: The user that submit this query: `submit_query(array('code1' => "code1", 'code2' => "code2"));` :)

Comment: But you could adapt the code of `submit_query` to order the array first, then to the request and in the target file order them again ... or am I missing something?

Comment: Since i want use it for API, i want give a choice to the user :)